# re.search() function in python not finding substring

Tags: python

The substring 'Failed to connect to host' is not being found in the 'text' variable. I am fairly new to python and I would appreciate any help.

```
import subprocess
import re

host = 'XXXXXXX'
output = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/ssh', '-q', host, 'ifconfig|', 'grep', 'Mask'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
text = output.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
pattern = 'Failed to connect to host'

if re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

The expected result should be "found" since the text str contains the pattern but for some reason, the result is "not found".

Actual Output:

```
Failed to connect to host XXXXXXX port 22: No route to host
not found
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the interests of creating a [mcve], if the subprocess stuff is working OK and producing the correct `text`, just eliminate that and hardcode in `text`. The problem is that we won't have the same environment and `ssh` dir as you, so it's unclear what `text` really is and I have no idea what I'm searching against.

Comment: It works fine when `text` is hardcoded as @ggorlen suggested. You might have a problem with your subprocess code. Have you checked if the message is printed to `stderr` instead of `stdout`?

Comment: Try printing 'output' and 'text' for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the error message is printed to stderr, but you're only matching against the text printed on stdout. If you try `print(repr(text))` you'll see it prints `''`.

Try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to your `Popen` call, like this:

```
output = subprocess.Popen([...], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
#                                                        ^-- this
```

What it does is it redirects stderr to stdout. See the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STDOUT